# pass KML to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

i found out that i can open google maps with a linkt to a kml-file like that:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example1.kml

that is exactly what i need, but i don't like to provide a public URL with the Data. Is it possible to pass the data with a post request or get parameter?

Or has anybody another idea how to create a link to google maps with multible markers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on your comment: You could upload the KML to a Google My Map: maps.google.com->My Places->Create Map->Import. There isn't currently programmatic access to My Maps. Otherwise, maps.google.com requires a public server to host the KML data.

Comment: hm, i dont want to display a map with markers on my page, there the user can't save the markers to his locations, or am i wrong?